# is it possible to change the energy of a waveform like radio wave & turn it into microwave?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency

In the electromagnetic spectrum, the differences between all waveforms are the "frequency" &  energy of the waveform.  We are able to modify both of these parameters. So, is it possible to change a waveform from one to another? If so, how? In particular, is it possible to change a radio transmitter to a microwave emitter?

Comment: I think you could use a klystron: http://www2.lbl.gov/MicroWorlds/ALSTool/ALS_Components/RFSystem/ to emmit in the radio-microwave range.

Answer (score 0):

Well, theorotically it seems possible, because we know that E=hv. So if we want to increase or decrease the frequency, there has to be a propotional increase or decrease in the energy of the EMR.